# Create JTable with one row

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Am trying to create a JTable which should have only one row in it and am using the following code,

```
        Object rowData[][] =  {{ "", "", "", "", "", ""},null} ;
        Object columnNames[] = { "A", "B", "C" , "D", "E", "F"};
        TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(rowData, columnNames);
        table = new JTable(model);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.NORTH); //in a JDialog
```

However i get the first row with **A,B,C,D,E,F** as `column names` and after that two empty rows are getting created whereas i need only one empty row.

How can i achieve this in JTable?

Am completely new to this .. please help.

Comment: If you want 1 row, why are you putting two values in your rowData array?

Comment: Seems , null from rowData is your second row , remove it.

Comment: @Ordous and alex2410 such a simple thing i couldnt get it and was trying all other possibilities. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am completely new to this

Check out the DefaultTableModel API. You missed a simple constructor that you can use:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 1);
JTable table = new JTable( model );
```